# How can I break margin, padding and background property?

Tags: jquery, html, css, background

For Example. I am using this code :

```
$(".sample").click(function() {
  var html = [],
    x = $(this).css([
      "margin", "padding", "color", "border"
    ]);

  $.each(x, function(prop, value) {
    html.push(prop + ": " + value);
  });

  $("#result").html(html.join("<br>"));


})
```

About the code :

This code is use to featch the css properties according to the given array x:

What I want :

I want that when the properties featch like margin, padding, background ( The properties which have more than one options ) it seperate to make it clear here is the example

For Margin and Padding

**if** margin/padding is 0

**margin/padding: 0;**

then

it will be printed out like this

**margin/padding =  0 0 0 0;**

**else if** margin/padding is something like 0 10 6 7

it will be printed out like this

**margin/padding : 0 10 6 7**

For Background

**if** background is url(../sample.jpg) 20px 20px no-repeat cover red

it will be printed out like this

**background-image = url(../sample.jpg)**

**backgound-top = 20px**

**backgound-center = 20px**

**background-repeat = no-repeat**

**background-cover = cover**

**background-color = red**

**else if** background-color is red or background-repeat is cover  // ( for this just want some hint )

it will be printed out like this

**background-color = red**

**background-repeat = no-repeat**

Answer (score 0):

Create a class like

```
.test{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
.newTest{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

and check in the loop like for all conditions:

```
if($('#yourElement').hasClass('test')){
     document.getElementById("yourElement").innerHTML = "margin/padding = 0 0 0 0;";
});
```